# Can persons employed on the H1/L1 visa run a small business on the side?

Tags: usa, h1-visa, l1-visa

If someone is employed for a company on the H1/L1 visa, they're not allowed to work for additional employers on the side. But is it permissible for those people to run a small business on the side, such as being a wedding photographer?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is *no,* but can't find a statute or regulation addressing this.  If I do, I'll post an answer.

Comment: The best I can find (on Quora/lawyer sites) is that you could be a silent partner--that is, do no active work for the business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that H1-B visas require that you have an employer-employee relationship (which means that 1099s are not acceptable) and any employment must be complaint to the H1-B regulations and approved in the USCIS forms, no you cannot.

For an L1 visa, the answer is also no because you can only work for the petitioning employer.